# pthread condition variables and mutex, program has a deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock

I'm having a problem with my multithreading code, there is a deadlock but I don't know how to fix it since I'm pretty new to pthreads.

The code below shows a function named "idle" that is waiting for a simulated process to be placed on a readyqueue, the push function is supposed to place that process on the queue and then signal that there is a process ready to be scheduled.

Here are the two functions that cause the deadlock:

```
void push(pcb_t *pcb) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = pcb;
        tail = pcb;
    } else {
        pcb_t *old_tail = tail;
        tail = pcb;
        old_tail->next = tail;
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&proc_ready);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
}
extern void idle(unsigned int cpu_id)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);

    while(head == NULL) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&proc_ready, &queue_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
    schedule(cpu_id);

    /*

     * idle() must block when the ready queue is empty, or else the CPU threads
     * will spin in a loop.  Until a ready queue is implemented, we'll put the
     * thread to sleep to keep it from consuming 100% of the CPU time.  Once
     * you implement a proper idle() function using a condition variable,
     * remove the call to mt_safe_usleep() below.
     */
}
```

Here is the gdb backtrace:

```
Thread 2 (Thread 0xb7df7b40 (LWP 3443)):
#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0xb7fb59e2 in __lll_lock_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/lowlevellock.S:144
No locals.
#2  0xb7fb1267 in _L_lock_847 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0xb7fb10a0 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x804c75c <queue_mutex>)
    at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:79
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "__pthread_mutex_lock"
        type = 0
        id = <optimized out>
#4  0x080489d9 in idle (cpu_id=0) at student.c:116
No locals.
#5  0x08048f65 in simulator_cpu_thread (cpu_id=0) at os-sim.c:259
        state = CPU_IDLE
#6  0x08049b4a in simulator_cpu_thread_func (data=0x0) at os-sim.c:618
No locals.
#7  0xb7faef70 in start_thread (arg=0xb7df7b40) at pthread_create.c:312
        __res = <optimized out>
        pd = 0xb7df7b40
        now = <optimized out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {-1208217600, -1210090688, 4001536, 
                -1210092504, -193645269, -1085428949}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {
            pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, 
              canceltype = 0}}}
        not_first_call = <optimized out>
        pagesize_m1 = <optimized out>
        sp = <optimized out>
        freesize = <optimized out>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "start_thread"
#8  0xb7ee5bee in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129
No locals.

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb7df8700 (LWP 3439)):
#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0xb7fb59e2 in __lll_lock_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/lowlevellock.S:144
No locals.
#2  0xb7fb1267 in _L_lock_847 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0xb7fb10a0 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x804c75c <queue_mutex>)
    at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:79
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "__pthread_mutex_lock"
        type = 0
        id = <optimized out>
#4  0x0804886f in push (pcb=0x804c660 <processes>) at student.c:42
No locals.
#5  0x08048acb in wake_up (process=0x804c660 <processes>) at student.c:205
No locals.
#6  0x08049a14 in simulate_io () at os-sim.c:590
        completed = 0x804d0f8
        pcb = 0x804c660 <processes>
#7  0x08048e0f in simulator_supervisor_thread () at os-sim.c:189
No locals.
#8  0x08048dcc in start_simulator (new_cpu_count=1) at os-sim.c:161
        n = 1
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "start_simulator"
#9  0x08048ba8 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff284) at student.c:240
        cpu_count = 1
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "main"
```

edit: pop function that also uses the queue_mutex

```
pcb_t * pop() {
    pcb_t *pcb = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else if (head == tail) {
        pcb = head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    } else {
        pcb = head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
    pcb->next = NULL;
    return pcb;
}
```

Comment: Is the mutex used anywhere else? If it is, you need to show that code too.

Comment: ok I added the only other function that uses the queue_mutex. It's at the bottom of the post.

Comment: pop: return NULL. does not unlock the mutex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pop function does not unlock the mutex when in the head == NULL case.

Comment: Thank you so much, moved the check outside the mutex lock and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your mutex object should have been locked in an appropriate way after controlling if head is `null` in `pop` function, otherwise it remained blocked. And also, `pthread_cond_signal` function may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling `pthread_cond_wait` has associated with the condition variable during its wait; however, if predictable scheduling behaviour is required, then that mutex is locked by the thread calling `pthread_cond_signal`.

Comment: Again, don't think that's correct. Read the pthread_cond_wait manual. It unlocks the mutex before blocking on the conditional var.

Comment: @AlanAu Actually, It is correct. Why don't you read pthread_cond_signal manual ? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html

Comment: I did read it. So maybe I'm not understanding your point. The given code structure is text book and is correct. So I don't understand your point. Have a look at the example in the pthread_cond_init manual page. It is exactly the structure that vicg has used.

Comment: @AlanAu I think there's been a misunderstanding. We're both saying the same thing over signal & wait functions differently. The problem was controlling list's head value before waiting for mutex object in appropriate signalling.

Answer (score -2):

Your **idle** function locks the **mutex**, and then spin locks on your **pthread_cond_wait**.  Then when the scheduler feels like it, the **push** function is allowed to execute, but the first thing the **push** function does is attempt to grab the **mutex**.  Unfortunately, the **mutex** is already owned by the **idle** thread.  Therefore the **push** thread blocks, waiting for the **mutex** to be freed, which will never happen, because the idle function is spin locking on the **pthread_cond_wait**.

Comment: I don't think that is right. Read the pthread_cond_wait manual. It unlocks the mutex before blocking on the conditional var.

Comment: Correct, I missed that the cond_wait call does in fact unlock the mutex first.